# pandas filtering by a boolean series

Tags: python, pandas

I am having issue where I am trying to filter a dataframe rows where the corresponding entry in a pandas series object is true.

So, looking at the dataset, I have my input dataframe with size:

```
[37697 rows x 12 columns]
```

And then I have the corresponding filtering series as:

```
0        False
1        False
2        False
3        False
4        False
         ...  
37692    False
37693    False
37694    False
37695    False
37696    False
Name: _merge, Length: 37697, dtype: bool
```

So, they have the same length but when I do something like:

```
df[df.columns[_merge]]
```

I get:

```
boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 12 but corresponding boolean dimension is 37697
```

I tried using `r.transpose()` but that still gives the same error.

Comment: Try `df[_merge]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df.columns` returns a list of **columns** in your DataFrame.

Then you wrote `[_merge]`, so you attempt to access columns using *boolean indexing*.

And since your column list has different length from the length of *_merge*,
an exception has been raised.

Try *boolean indexing*, but on **rows** of your DataFrame:

```
df[_merge]
```